# Number of the possible arrays that can be formed from a string of digits ( Leetcode 1416. Restore The Array )

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, backtracking

Given the leetcode question [1416. Restore The Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/restore-the-array/description/):

> A program was supposed to print an array of integers. The program
> forgot to print whitespaces and the array is printed as a string of
> digits s and all we know is that all integers in the array were in the
> range [1, k] and there are no leading zeros in the array.
>
> Given the string s and the integer k, return the number of the
> possible arrays that can be printed as s using the mentioned program.

I'm trying to solve this question using backtracking, but I can't understand why my solution returns an incorrect output.

```py
class Solution:
    def numberOfArrays(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        ans = 0

        def backtrack(s, index, buffer):
            nonlocal ans, k

            # If we have reached the end of the string,
            # we have found a valid array of integers.
            if index == len(s):
                ans += 1
                return

            # If the current digit is '0', we cannot form
            # a valid number using any of the following digits.
            if s[index] == "0":
                return

            # Try forming a number using the current digit and
            # the following digits. If the number is valid,
            # continue the backtracking process with the remaining
            # digits in the string.
            for i in range(index, len(s)):
                buffer *= 10
                buffer += int(s[i])
                if buffer <= k:
                    backtrack(s, i + 1, buffer)
                else:
                    # If the number is not valid, stop the backtracking
                    # process and undo any changes made to the buffer.
                    buffer //= 10

        backtrack(s, 0, 0)
        return ans
```

It is able to pass the following test cases:

```
Input: s = "1000", k = 10000
Output: 1

Input: s = "1000", k = 10
Output: 0

Input: s = "1317", k = 2000
Output: 8
```

But not this one:

```
Input: s = "2020", k = 30
Output: 0
Expected: 1
```

I don't understand why it can't detect the partition `[20, 20]`.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop in your backtracking algorithm is incorrect.

if `buffer <= k`, then there is a choice to either

- carry the `buffer` forward (as `backtrack(s, i + 1, buffer)`), OR
- see `buffer` as an element in the result array. In this case you need to reset the buffer and calls `backtrack` again.

  - because of this, the algo failed to detect the `[20, 20]` case

if `buffer > k`, you should break out of the for-loop instead of continuing it, because there is a chance that in the next iteration `buffer` may become `<= k` and calls `backtrack` (and you really don't want that). You can try the test case `s = "91", k = 3` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works. The main problem with my original code, besides [what has already been mentioned by @nicku123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74941516/4882300), is that we should have a counter and a buffer that is set to zero on every call to the backtracking function.

```py
class Solution:
    def numberOfArrays(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        cache = {}
        def backtrack(pos: int) -> int:
            original_pos = pos
            count = 0
            buffer = 0
            if pos in cache:
                return cache[pos]
            for i in range(pos, len(s)):
                buffer *= 10 
                buffer += int(s[i])
                if buffer <= k and i+1 <= len(s)-1 and s[i+1] != '0':
                    count += (backtrack(i+1) % 1000000007)
                if buffer > k:
                    break
            else:
                if buffer <= k:
                    count += 1
            cache[original_pos] = count
            return count
        return backtrack(0) % 1000000007
```